# Raspberry Pi not booting whn etxernal disk fails to mount via Fstab

Tags: power-supply, pi-3, hard-drive

I have a raspberry pi that has an external drive that mounts via fstab. Sometimes the pi refuses to boot when the external drive doesn't spin up fast enough (albeit the drive is quite old). Is there any way to force the pi to force the drive?

Device - Raspberry Pi 3
OS - Raspbian
Hard Disk - 1TB Portable Seagate External (No External Power Supply)
Raspberry - Power supply Apple 10W Charger 5.1V 2.1A
Mount Method - fstab (

/dev/sda1 /media/rfts auto noatime 0 0

Comment: You have provided NO information. What Pi? What `fstab`? What power? Have you measured voltage?

Comment: Sorry for that - have updated with relevant details.

Comment: You still haven't described your power supply or voltage. The `fstab` also appears to contain errors (try `autofs` or better actually specify actual fs), but if the Pi won't boot it is more likely to be a power issue. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47642/8697. The Pi3 Should work with a good supply, but these seem to be rare.

Comment: @milliways Have added the power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it hasn't got enough power to spin up fast. There are two solutions:

- Set **max_usb_current=1** setting in */boot/config.txt*
- Use USB HUB with external power

Comment: This text isn't in my config.txt. Have added it. But, shouldn't it be min_usb_current=1