# USB HDD on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

Tags: pi-2, hard-drive, usb-power

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and a 2,5 inch HDD that I want to connect via USB. The HDD also powers itself over USB. Does the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B provide enough power? Can I safely run the HDD without breaking any of the two devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You SHOULD be able to power a HDD from the Pi2 (provided you use an adequate power supply AND set `max_usb_current=1`). The max USB current is 600/1200mA depending on `max_usb_current`

Unfortunately adequate power supplies are not common. See the comments in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/47642/8697 Even though this is Pi3 the issues are the same and the power circuitry very similar.

Comment: Any quick hint where to set (and as well check) `max_usb_current` to `1`? How much mA does Pi 2 Model B provide without this setting on USB?

Comment: @Socrates add `max_usb_current=1` to your `config.txt` file. you can access this file by connecting your pi's sd card into a laptop. also it will raise the current limit from the usual 500ma to approximately 1200ma

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it does not! You can harm your RPi board seriously if you will power your HDD from it, *even attaching a 5Amp PSU* : the RPi board is simply not designed for such currents. Use a USB hub with external PSU and it will be OK, or - if you're about to use just a one more PSU for your HDD, **make sure you've connected it's GND(Ground) with the one supplied to RPi**

Comment: Some 2,5" HDD for USB2.0 do run with a single connector and thus presumably with <= 500 mA which would most likely ok for the Pi if the power supply could handle it.

Comment: What is the maximum current for USB devices on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

Comment: @Ghanima I don't doubt a PSU - it can supply even a 10 amps... The problem lays on PCB's current ratings: take a look [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb20_docs/) and keep in mind, that NIC+4USB is a *single* USB outlet

Comment: @Socrates I do recommend you not to exceed 200 miliAmps per device. On my RPi2 250+ mA **did** caused problems: tested it on hi-power USB WiFi adapters

Comment: other answers claim otherwise e.g. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27708/19949

Comment: @Ghanima tried, not working: not in Raspbian, not on latest Git kernel

Comment: What rubbish! Why do you think the Pi2 has a 2A polyfuse (and the Pi3 2.5A) if the board was not designed for it.

Comment: @Milliways actually - it **can** be fused even for 3A per USB output - a form-factor and a standartds does not prohibit it... But **it is not** - I agree, I learned this lesson in a hard way by attaching a various hi-power USB WiFi dongles that worked *just perfectly* on a regular PC. I actually don't understand why the RPi makers either make a **proper** soldering or make just one USB outlet...